# Gchart com Django

Tags: python, django, google-charts

Oi estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Django que cria gráficos. E já implementei um gráfico de linha utilizando o GCharts [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://github.com/rhblind/django-gcharts) porém só possui uma linha, e no exemplo eu já vi como criar o mesmo gráfico com várias linhas, porém somente com um número fixo. E para o meu caso eu preciso criar para n linhas (sendo n o número de Tags que eu possuo no Database).

Aqui está Model das classes necessárias:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtag = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAG', primary_key=True, editable=False, verbose_name = 'Id')  # Field name made lowercase.
    desvio = models.FloatField(db_column='DEVIATION', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Diversion')  # Field name made lowercase.
    tempo_max = models.IntegerField(db_column='TIME_MAX', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Max time')  # Field name made lowercase.
    conv_rate = models.IntegerField(db_column='CONV_RATE', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Convertion rate')  # Field name made lowercase.
    taginfo_idtaginfo1 = models.ForeignKey('Taginfo', db_column='tagInfo_idTAGINFO', verbose_name = 'Tag')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datasource_idestacao_meteo = models.ForeignKey(Datasource, db_column='datasource_idDATASOURCE', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Datasource')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'id = %s / id tagInfo => %s' % (self.idtag, self.taginfo_idtaginfo1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tag'


class Taginfo(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtaginfo = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAGINFO', primary_key=True, editable=False, verbose_name = 'Id')  # Field name made lowercase.
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=45, verbose_name = 'Name')  # Field name made lowercase.
    descricao = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name = 'Details')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'name = %s / description = %s' % (self.nome, self.descricao)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'taginfo'


class Valores(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idvalores = models.IntegerField(db_column='idVALUES', primary_key=True, editable=False, verbose_name = 'Id')  # Field name made lowercase.
    valor = models.FloatField(db_column='VALUE', verbose_name = 'Value')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datahora = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATETIME', verbose_name = 'Date time')  # Field name made lowercase.
    tag_idtag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, db_column='tag_idTAG', verbose_name = 'Tag')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Tag = %s  / DATETIME = %s / Value = %s' % (self.tag_idtag, self.datahora, self.valor)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'values'
```

E a view que eu fiz para gerar o gráfico com uma linha:

```
def tag(request, tag_id = 1):
# if there is
if Tag.objects.filter(idtag=tag_id).count()>0 :
    result = Tag.objects.get(idtag=tag_id)

    hasInfo = False
    tagInfo = None
    #if there is information about this tag
    if Taginfo.objects.filter(idtaginfo = result.taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo).count() > 0:
        tagInfo = Taginfo.objects.get(idtaginfo = result.taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo)
        hasInfo = True
    #if there is values on this tag 
    if Valores.objects.filter(tag_idtag = tag_id).count>0:
        aux = Valores.objects.filter(tag_idtag = tag_id)
        #this verify is only to put the description on the graph
        if hasInfo:
            values = aux.order_by('-datahora').to_json(order=("datahora", "valor"),
                                                    labels={"valor": tagInfo.descricao})
        else:
            values = aux.order_by('-datahora').to_json(order=("datahora", "valor"),
                                                    labels={"valor": "Values"})
    else:
        values = None
    return render_to_response('Tag/tag.html',
        {'tag' : result, 'values' : values, 'tagInfo' : tagInfo}
    )
else:
    return render_to_response('Tag/tagDoesNotExist.html',
        {'tag_id' : tag_id }
    )
```

Porém como faria para criar uma função que me retornasse um gráfico de linha com n linhas??

Comment: Nathan, por que você está usando `db_column='nome_da_coluna'`? Por que definir um `primary_key` se o Django faz isso automaticamente? Eu particularmente olho o seu código e fico confuso com essas nomenclaturas  que você utiliza (ex: taginfo_idtaginfo1).

Comment: Pq na verdade esse projeto é em conjunto. É um projeto de Iniciação Científica de universidade, eu e mais outro estudante trabalhamos juntos. E o professor queria que o Django utilizasse o DB que já existia, então eu utiizei comando `python manage.py inspextdb` para o Django criar os models apartir do DB existente. E neste DB foi criado pelo outro componente, não tive participação alguma com a nomenclatura dos campos no DB.